# Discover all devices on LAN

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

In my Xamarin Forms application, I am trying to discover all devices on the local network that I am connected to. My approach is to first get the device IP address, and use to first 3 numbers to know what the gateway is (first number is always 192). And then, ping every address on that gateway. Here is my code:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    private List<Device> discoveredDevices = new List<Device>();

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Ping_all();
    }

    private string GetCurrentIp()
    {
        IPAddress[] addresses = Dns.GetHostAddresses(Dns.GetHostName());
        string ipAddress = string.Empty;
        if (addresses != null && addresses[0] != null)
        {
            ipAddress = addresses[0].ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            ipAddress = null;
        }

        return ipAddress;
    }

    public void Ping_all()
    {
        string ip = GetCurrentIp();

        if (ip != null)
        {
            //Extracting and pinging all other ip's.
            string[] array = ip.Split('.');
            string gateway = array[0] + "." + array[1] + "." + array[2];

            for (int i = 2; i <= 255; i++)
            {
                string ping_var = $"{gateway}.{i}";

                //time in milliseconds           
                Ping(ping_var, 4, 4000);
            }
        }
    }

    public void Ping(string host, int attempts, int timeout)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < attempts; i++)
        {
            new Thread(delegate ()
            {
                try
                {
                    System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping ping = new System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping();
                    ping.PingCompleted += new PingCompletedEventHandler(PingCompleted);
                    ping.SendAsync(host, timeout, host);
                    // PingCompleted never gets called
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    // Do nothing and let it try again until the attempts are exausted.
                    // Exceptions are thrown for normal ping failurs like address lookup
                    // failed.  For this reason we are supressing errors.
                }
            }).Start();
        }
    }

    private void PingCompleted(object sender, PingCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        string ip = (string)e.UserState;
        if (e.Reply != null && e.Reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
        {
            string hostname = GetHostName(ip);
            string macaddres = GetMacAddress(ip);

            var device = new Device()
            {
                Hostname = hostname,
                IpAddress = ip,
                MacAddress = macaddres
            };

            discoveredDevices.Add(device);
        }
    }

    public string GetHostName(string ipAddress)
    {
        try
        {
            IPHostEntry entry = Dns.GetHostEntry(ipAddress);
            if (entry != null)
            {
                return entry.HostName;
            }
        }
        catch (SocketException)
        {

        }

        return null;
    }

    public string GetMacAddress(string ipAddress)
    {
        string macAddress = string.Empty;
        System.Diagnostics.Process Process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        Process.StartInfo.FileName = "arp";
        Process.StartInfo.Arguments = "-a " + ipAddress;
        Process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        Process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        Process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        Process.Start();
        string strOutput = Process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        string[] substrings = strOutput.Split('-');
        if (substrings.Length >= 8)
        {
            macAddress = substrings[3].Substring(Math.Max(0, substrings[3].Length - 2))
                     + "-" + substrings[4] + "-" + substrings[5] + "-" + substrings[6]
                     + "-" + substrings[7] + "-"
                     + substrings[8].Substring(0, 2);
            return macAddress;
        }
        else
        {
            return "OWN Machine";
        }
    }
}
```

I get to the part where I try to ping:

```
System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping ping = new System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping();
ping.PingCompleted += new PingCompletedEventHandler(PingCompleted);
ping.SendAsync(host, timeout, host);
```

But `PingCompleted` never gets called. No exception is thrown either. Any idea why? I'm running this on a physical Android device.

**EDIT**

`PingCompleted` started getting called for me now, not sure why it wasn't working before. But it now crashes in my `GetMacAddress` function on the line `Process.Start();` because it can not find the resource.

Comment: not every device responds to a ping request

Comment: Neither here nor there, but the gateway is not always at `x.x.x.1`.  I've often seen it at `x.x.x.255`.

Comment: I tried using the Fing app from the Google Play Store and it finds 14 different devices. So it must be something I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Kirk, but the first 3 numbers are always the same for each device on a local network, right?

Comment: It depends on subnet mask if it is ip/24 yes same but otherwise it is not

Comment: I don't think pro network scan tools rely entirely on ping requests

Comment: Yikes...maybe I should change my approach. Any suggestions?

Comment: you should use the Netmask... its a combination of the subnetmark and the ip address.  And your best bet would be to try and ARP... but that isn't 100% and there can be layer 2 devices that dont have IP addresses.

Comment: there are many other posts on SO about doing network discovery using C#

Comment: @Darius but your loop is `for (int i = 2; i <= 255; i++)` which, by starting at `2`, I believe you are discounting `1` by presuming it's the gateway?

Comment: Note that `arp` (in this context) is a Windows command/program and is unlikely to work on a non-Windows device. On a phone/mobile device there isn't much use for `Process.Start()` other than to open a local file or URLs/URIs.

Comment: @KirkWoll You might have seen it at another address, but I assure you it wasn't 255.  That's the Broadcast port.  Drake You shouldn't assume your network is 192.  My work network is 10.x.x.x.  It is entirely configurable by whomever manages a network.  10 is quite common for businesses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using this really robust and easy to use library:

https://github.com/Yortw/RSSDP

It doesn't actually find all devices on the network, instead it uses SSDP (Simple Search Discovery Protocol) to quickly find all devices that are broadcasting a service with this protocol on the network. I filtered it to only scan devices running my app, which is what I actually needed. It takes only a second to discover my devices, which is much faster than pinging 255 addresses.

In the documentation you will see:

```
var deviceDefinition = new SsdpRootDevice()
{
    CacheLifetime = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30), //How long SSDP clients can cache this info.
    Location = new Uri("http://mydevice/descriptiondocument.xml"), // Must point to the URL that serves your devices UPnP description document. 
    DeviceTypeNamespace = "my-namespace",
    DeviceType = "MyCustomDevice",
    FriendlyName = "Custom Device 1",
    Manufacturer = "Me",
    ModelName = "MyCustomDevice",
    Uuid = GetPersistentUuid() // This must be a globally unique value that survives reboots etc. Get from storage or embedded hardware etc.
};
```

For the `Location` I set it as my device's IP. So that another device that discovers it can have the IP too. I don't think it's meant to be used this way, but it worked for me and I don't see why not.

I tested it on 2 physical Android devices.

Comment: Darius, I am too new to Xamarin and SSDP, and need some help , I too need a device discovery APP, and would need a sample code on how to get done. I hove been looking every where until  I humped into your post. please help me out.

Comment: Your requirements may differ from mine. I need to discover devices that are running my app, not all the devices. If that's what you need, install the plugin as a nuget package. Follow the sample code in the documentation to see how to publish a device, as well as discover other devices. Then do as I suggested in my post and set the `Location` as your IP address. I no longer have the sample code that I wrote as I moved on to a different project.